# Uncaught TypeError: ... is not a constructor - Typescript module import error

Tags: typescript, import, module

I have an example typscript project which I have cloned from github and installed with npm install.

In the index.ts I am trying to import a third party module (https://github.com/ScatterCo/Depthkit.js).  This module has been downloaded into the node_modules folder using `npm install depthkit`

To import the module I have tried both
`import {DepthKit} from 'depthkit/build/depthkit';`
or  `import * as DK from 'depthkit/build/depthkit';`

But when I run `var depthkit = new DepthKit();` or `var depthkit = new DK.DepthKit();`
I am getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: depthkit_1.DepthKit is not a constructor`

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the code I read the correct import should be `import DepthKit from "depthkit"` as the DepthKit class is the index default export

Comment: Thanks but the depthkit.js file does not exist at the root of the depthkit folder in node_modules, its actually in depthkit/build/depthkit.js   are you saying I do not need to specifically direct the importer to this js file path?